# Symfony2: version 2.0.1 and DoctrineMigrationsBundle

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, database-migration

All!
What is going on ? 
Today I trying to reinstall new version of Symfony2 (2.0.1) from GitHub

```
$ app/vendors install --reinstall
```

with my Kernel & autoloader configs:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
  public function registerBundles()
  {
    $bundles = array(
      new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
      new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
      new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
      new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
      new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
      new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
      new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
      new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
      ...

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
  'Symfony'          => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
  'Sensio'           => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
  'JMS'              => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
  'Doctrine\\Common\\DataFixtures' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-fixtures/lib',
  'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Migrations' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-migrations/lib',
  'Doctrine\\Common' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
  'Doctrine\\DBAL'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
  'Doctrine'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',
  'Monolog'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/monolog/src',
  'Assetic'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/assetic/src',
  'Metadata'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/metadata/src',
```

));

File [Symfony2-root]/deps

```
[doctrine-migrations]
  git=http://github.com/doctrine/migrations.git

[DoctrineMigrationsBundle]
  git=http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineMigrationsBundle.git

[doctrine-fixtures]
  git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
  git=http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
```

but got an strange error:
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle' not found in

Does somebody knows what is going on ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Solved.
My mistake

I forgot to add one line in deps

```
[DoctrineMigrationsBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineMigrationsBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMigrationsBundle
```

instead of

```
[DoctrineMigrationsBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineMigrationsBundle.git
```

Now everything is ok.